# CMFCStatusBar change height when the icon is added

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

In my application there is CMFCStatusBar. I add icon to this bar as follow:

```
m_wndStatusBar.SetPaneIcon(m_wndStatusBar.CommandToIndex(ID_INDICATOR_ZOOM),GetApp()->LoadIcon(IDR_ZOOM));
```

Size of this icon is 16x16 px. After adding this icon, the height of this bar is changed to 32px. Do you know, what I can do to avoid this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`LoadImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `LoadIcon` and specify the desired icon size directly, e.g.:

```
::LoadImage(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ZOOM), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_SHARED);
```

Comment: Good answer, this solves the problem. Note that the returned `HANDLE` can be cast to `HICON`, e.g.:
`hIcon = (HICON)::LoadImage(::AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_ZOOM), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_SHARED);`